Journals to publish blockchain + cryptography related results
I am finding it hard to find good journals to publish cryptographic applications over blockchains where theoretical contributions are present but not significant enough for a top tier venue. Can someone give me an opinion? Also what is people's opinion on open access journals like IEEE Access, Journal of cybersecurity (Oxford)?
